# GCP VM deployment issues - The zone 'projects/xxxxx/zones/europe-west2-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-cloud-vm

Using Cisco vManage to deploy virtual routers into Google Cloud via the automated features to create 2 new VMs (one for each router). It was working in the Europe-west2 region last month, but now gives me the error about not having enough resources. I can deploy in US-WEST1 for example without any issues.

Variables in the requests are:

```
  "machineType": "n1-standard-4",

  "diskInfoList": [
    {
      "sourceImage": "projects/cisco-public/global/images/cisco-c8k-17-06-02",
      "diskSizeGb": 16,
      "type": "PERSISTENT",
      "mode": "READ_WRITE",
      "boot": true
    }
```

I get this failure code.

```
  "mcCtxt": {
    "tenantId": "xxxxx",
    "ctxId": "createGcpVmInstances"
  },
  "status": {
    "code": "FAILED",
    "errString": "The zone 'projects/xxxxxx/zones/europe-west2-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or try again later."
  }
}
```

I have checked the quotas and there doesn't seem to be an issue.

Is there a way of finding the reason in GCP why it is happening and where the issue is?

Thanks in advance.
Neal

I have deployed into different regions like US-WEST1 without issue, but some regions have the problem. I have checked the quotas and that does not seem to be an issue. I have seen this issue for the last few days without change.

I would not expect google to run out of compute resources in lots of locations.

Answer (score 0):

**As you are getting below error :**

`The zone 'projects/PROJECT_ID/zones/ZONE' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request`.  States that this is a resource error and you need Try a different zone, or try again later.

Resource errors occur when you try to request new resources in a zone that cannot accommodate your request due to the current unavailability of a Compute Engine resource, such as GPUs or CPUs.

The reason for this behavior is resource availability which depends on users requests and therefore are dynamic; you can find the same in this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability).

**Below are few ways to solve such issue:**

- Try to create the resources in another zone in the region or in another region.
- [Move your VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones) to [another zone](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection).
- If you were unable to resolve the error using any of the preceding instructions, [try Getting support](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/getting-support).

You can check the status of Google Cloud at [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/).