# This version has no instances deployed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

My application was working till the last day but suddenly it was stopped. when I checked in the app engine in my-service (in the current version) then I found that there is no instance available for my-service.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: app.yaml]

I have restarted the version.
increased the limit to IAM Admin section >  quotas
try to deploy a new version but it failed and shows the below error
[The region us-east1 does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.

**Is there anyone who can give the solution to this problem**
**My whole application is stopped and I have no solution**

Comment: This is because the region: “us-east1” does not have enough resources to meet the request to create the new VM Instance at this moment. Additionally, I can confirm that the error has nothing to do with your project quota but absolutely related to the availability of resources for that region, There are many similar stack questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74600628/deployment-issue-using-gcp) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74474121/gcp-vm-deployment-issues-the-zone-projects-xxxxx-zones-europe-west2-b-does-n/74475732#74475732)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Sai Chandra Gadde
can you tell me how much time it will take to up (us-east1)

Comment: Look's like the issue with Google App Engine has been resolved for all affected projects can you check now and let us know, Issue has been mentioned in Public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/260280330).